# How can i build a machine learning model to identify a specific word?

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining

I am trying to build a model that can be used to identify the word sales whenever a group of text are passed through the model. Should I use Azure or Python for this? I have done the text preprocessing and extracted the n-gram features in Azure, what should I do next and which model should I use?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of your data please. Are they just simple text? If so, why don't you just look for instances of the character string "sale" throughout the text?

Comment: "Hi, there, Amanda, please. Take me. Sale." that is a sample of a transformed audio recording. I am trying to build a model to identifying the word "sale" in all the other groups of transformed recordings. I am an amateur at this, could you please describe to me how I can go about looking for the instances of the character string "sale" throughout the text?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is always best to approach a problem using the simplest possible tools. In your case there is no need to use a machine learning (AI) model to detect the word sale.

To find the word sale within a long datastream, I would do the following: parse through the entire String while looking at segments of size 4 at a time, convert the substring to lowercase. Determine if this substring is "sale". If it is save the index of the "s" into a list. Return the list which will include the index of each start of the word sale within your text.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getIndexSale(String inputString){
   ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
   String[] queue = new String[4];

   queue[0] = 0;
   queue[1] = 0;
   queue[2] = 0;
   queue[3] = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i<inputString.length(); i++){
      queue[0] = queue[1];
      queue[1] = queue[2];
      queue[2] = queue[3];
      queue[3] = inputString.charAt(i);

      String temp = java.util.Arrays.toString(queue).toLowerCase();

      if(temp.equals("sale"))  indexes.add(i);
   }

   return indexes;
}
```

As mentioned by Dan Carter: if you do not care about the indices of the word "sale" within your string then it is simpler to use:

```
public boolean getIndexSale(String inputString){

   if(inputString.toLowerCase().contains("sale")) return true;
   return false;
}
```

Comment: Could't agree more with this, but since your code example is in Java why not just use String.contains()? I don't think OP cares about the 'index' of the word in the sentence, just whether the word is in the String or not.

If indexes are needed, then I'd suggest using the .split(" ") method on the text after removing full stops and commas etc, to get an array of  individual words and index them that way. Your code example seems unnecessarily complex, as you said yourself, use the simplest possible tools :)

Comment: I was trying to make it readable for the OP. If the OP doesn't care about indices then boolean would suffice. Of course String.contains() would be easier. It also depends on how long the String bitstream is. Perhaps it is read from a super long file where you cannot check String.contains() directly. In which case you can use String.contains() in parts

Comment: Understood. +1 for your edit :)